# What's the fastest way to check if a list contains an item in Go?

Tags: arrays, list, go, optimization

I have a project where performance is very important. The function I have to check if a list contains an item is being called hundreds of thousand to millions of times per second, and is costing me a lot of time. It is responsible for 60% of the runtime of my program.

Currently, it looks like this:

```
func byteContains(list[]byte,item byte)bool{
    for _,value:=range list{
        if value==item{return true}
    }
    return false
}
```

This works, but it's slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Store those bytes in a map, and check if that item exists in the map. You are doing a linear search, which is O(n). Map lookup is amortized O(1). Or, sort the byte slice and do a binary search.

Comment: @BurakSerdar How do I check if an item exists in a map?

Comment: `_,exists:=m[item]`

Comment: Your question is vague on details. E.g. the code with a list of bytes makes no sense as there are only 256 bytes and a bitvector directly indexed would be the most sensible for the code you showed. Assuming this is is toy/pseudo-code (as the bitvector solution is trivial): You might want to look into Bloom and Cuckoo filters for a quick (but probablistic) way to test membership if your "list" is something that doesn't change a lot.

Comment: @Volker This isn't pseudocode. This is actual Go code. They don't change a lot. They're two different 8-item lists. I'm not sure what you mean by it makes no sense though.

Comment: Then convert the list (actually the slice `list []byte`) to a `vec []bool` where vec[b]==true iff list contains b. This reduces you lookup to `return vec[item]`.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that. That's incredibly smart. Thank you!

Comment: "That's incredibly smart" Actually no, this is standard textbook material. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Volker I've never read a computer science textbook; I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to allocate 256 bytes for your byte set, you can simplify your linear look-up to a direct memory lookup by offset:

```golang
type Set [256]bool

func (s *Set) Contains(b byte) bool {
    return s[b]
}

func (s *Set) Add(b byte) {
    s[b] = true
}

func (s *Set) Remove(b byte) {
    s[b] = false
}
```

Possible performance concerns:

- `Contains` will work equivalently with `Set` and `*Set` as the receiver type. It's possible that one of these will be faster, but it would likely depend on how you use the function and what optimizations the compiler applies. So, try both ways if performance is critical.
- If your byte values are all less than a certain value, you could reduce the size of the `Set` array to save some memory. However, keeping the size at (least) 256 will prevent the need for index bounds checking, which might save you some run-time overhead. Again, try it both ways if performance is essential.

Comment: Since there's only 20 possible values for the byte (I'm working in %32, don't ask if you don't want a long explanation), I'll use a very similar solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Flummox Interesting. I added another note on performance which you may find relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is the same list that is being checked or if there are few lists and the lookups are indeed orders of magnitude more frequent than updates, convert the list into a map.

Make the items be the keys and the values some placeholder value like `true`. Key lookup in maps is O(1), while item lookup in list is O(n).

Comment: This works, but it's actually slower. The lists I'm checking are only 8 items long, so the constant lookup time seems to still be slower.

Comment: Replace your map and item arguments with a pointer to the map and the argument, as you are duplicating both values every time you run the function, which has performance and memory costs.

Comment: If your lists are this small and will always be this small, then indeed it might be better to just use the list unless you can combine them somehow. Maybe use the items as keys and the list identifier as a value? I don't know without knowing better the project details. However, you do need to replace the arguments with pointer to arguments, otherwise Go will recreate and garbage collect them on every function run.

Comment: That's what I had been doing, actually. I will use pointers instead, but that doesn't seem to have much impact.